# javascript prototype property

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a short question about prototypes.

An object that has the prototype of a `Square` function inherits the prototype of a `Rectangle` function, but of course not all rectangles are squares.Suppose an instance of `Rectangle` has its own properties `width` and `height` changed so that it becomes a square, how can this instance inherit the `Square` 
prototype when it is actually a square? Also, given a `Square` instance, how can it lose the `Square` prototype when it is no longer a square?

Comment: Objects don't "lose" prototypes like that (and "standard" OO inheritance also doesn't work that way). Your problem is actually [a common one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Comment: I an option you could consider is throwing an error in the width() & height() methods to ensure the values are set correctly depending on the shape criteria.

Answer (score 2):

It can't. Inheritance doesn't work like that.

In general, if you were creating a Square that inherited from a Rectangle, then it would override the functions for setting the height and width so that setting one would set the other and it could never be anything other than a square (and a Rectangle with equal sides would be square by coincidence and not in code).

If you want an object where sometimes it behaves differently if the height and width are the same, then put a test like `if (this.height === this.width)` in the functions where that matters.